Where to find the code behind npm init command or tsc --init command
I am trying to find the code behind the cli commands like
npm init
tsc --init
I tried looking for it in the node repo and typescript repo but couldnt find it yet.
can anyone please help me.
I cant find any similar question on stackoverflow as well.
Many thanks.

It's in the respective github repos, and not too hard to find really if you just navigate around a little:
https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/latest/lib/commands/init.js
